# Stack Overflow doesn't need [enhancement]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I was somewhat disappointed that this wasn't about herbal supplements. But then that would be about something, and this is about nothing.

[enhancement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enhancement)

66 questions, no excerpt, and no clue what is tying any of these together.

Comment: -1, not enhanced with red free hand circles ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll enhance the question using jQuery instead

Comment: @pnuts It has to have Meta sanction before we can start editing out tags because it's over 50 questions, though, right?

Comment: @pnuts, also, there's still [tag:goal] (which has 65 questions) before even considering this post.... so this'll have to wait. It's probably [tag:functionality] after [tag:movement].

Comment: @pnuts Yup, true. [movement] was at 300 questions, when it was raised, it was at 960 when it got featured (I had to rush before it hit the 1000, where CMs had to be involved, and ...). The tags itself are a big mess... :\  ... as of now, I'm interleaving a 50-150 questions burn in between the large ones (like [hijack] in between [ibm] and [movement] so that we can get rid of the small ones faster). I'm thinking of [functionality]  (145), then [orders] (660), then [ticket] (66), then one of the large tags, then [kali-linux] (82) ...

Comment: And not just that, we don't have a system in place to deal with a few types of burns, we gotta fix that as well.

Comment: @pnuts He's not entirely alone. SOCVR has had a sub-project started by Jon Clements where we helped to organize some of the burnination chaos. I know Rob has been doing some with these behind the scenes as well. So I'm optimistic we might get the backlog cleaned out and that it won't take years.

Comment: @pnuts, even with the current momentum, it'll take 3years to complete everything.

Comment: Btw, Rob has started to play an active role, and he'd mostly be conducting the large scale burninations soon ...

Comment: Interesting, there's also the tag [tag:progressive], which is used by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144460/progressive-enhancement-for-lazy-loading-images-javascript

Comment: This is clearly about the groundbreaking technique used in various crime shows to miraculously enhance the quality of grainy security photos or videos; it makes sense there's not much info about it here because it's a carefully guarded trade secret. My guess is the ~60 questions here are attempts to replicate that wild technological breakthrough.

Comment: It's supposed to work with the [tag:zoom] tag.

Comment: All questions are now closed.