# If Trogdor wore glasses, would they be [progressive]s?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [progressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive) tag has 79 questions, no usage guidance, and no clear meaning. The only thing that's clear about the tag is that it should be burninated. Can we do so?

To cover the criteria:

- **Does it unambiguously describe the content of the question?** Not at all. What is the term even supposed to mean?
- **Is it on topic?** Too many possible meanings to know.
- The tag is too vague to add any meaningful information to the post
- I don't know if it means the same thing in all common contexts because we aren't even sure what it means in the first place.

Comment: I see a _lot_ of questions with that tag that are about [Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/). Maybe a clean-up and a rename is in order?

Comment: Really thought this one would be a pun about Flo and the [Progressive](https://www.progressive.com/) insurance company...

Comment: I didn't look earlier but there is actually a [tag:progressive-web-apps] tag with 983 questions currently, a... better tag wiki and excerpt, and what seems to be very consistent usage. I recommend cleaning up the [tag:progressive] tag, then making it a synonym of [tag:progressive-web-apps]. That would prevent further usage of the arguably ambiguously named but not overly misused tag, and prevent users who are asking questions about progressive topics that are not related to Progressive web apps from tagging as such.

Comment: @TinyGiant That would work too

Comment: IMHO, tag called just `progressive` is as useless as a tag called `easy` or `green`..

Comment: Related burnination request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371492/stack-overflow-doesnt-need-enhancement

Comment: What? No jokes about the political usage of the term?

Comment: @jpmc26 Maybe the Supreme Court of StackOverflow should strike down this [progressive] tag?

Comment: @TylerH Think burninate, think [progressive].

Comment: @rgettman I think that this is something that both [progressive]s and conservatives can agree on.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please burninate this tag. It is actively harming questions for the following reason:

Questions that should be getting tagged [progressive-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive-web-apps) are getting tagged simply [progressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive), probably because [progressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive) (with 23 watchers) is shorter or comes up first. Thus, people who follow the [progressive-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive-web-apps) tag (487 watchers) aren't seeing these questions that they could help answer.

Examples:

[Progressive Web App Launching Native Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421129/progressive-web-app-launching-native-android-app) -- Tagged [progressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive) and NOT tagged [progressive-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive-web-apps) like it should be.

[Browser focus on PWA apps after sending SMS via SMS url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976294/browser-focus-on-pwa-apps-after-sending-sms-via-sms-url) Same issue; PWA is supposed to be [progressive-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive-web-apps) but it's only tagged [progressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive).

It's not a very frequent issue, questions appear this way about once per month, but... it's happening, and all because the worthless tag [progressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive) exists. If it were burninated, this wouldn't happen at all.

Comment: Why not make it a synonym? Then it cannot be created again. If we burninate it then the next person who has > 1500 rep that types "progressive web apps" into the tag bar will create it again and we'll have this problem all over again.

Comment: Don't make it a synonym, it seems a lot of the questions in this category are also being used to discuss ["progressive jpeg"](https://optimus.keycdn.com/support/progressive-jpeg/). A synonym should not be in order.